# How to go to new Html page from PHP script?

Tags: php, html

After the php script is over, how do I go to another html page?

Comment: can you be more specific about what your php script is doing?  it isn't dynamically generating html?

Comment: Basically, after finished with a login script, I want to go to another page

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Why would you want to do that? When the *page is over* (which I understand as *the script ended execution*), it is usually sent to the client and then it can be viewed by the user. So, basically, what you are trying to do is to redirect the user after the script stopped executing.

If so, you have two solutions available:

1. Do not output anything, and after your script stopped executing, **use the `header()` PHP function**:

   ```
   header('Location: http://example.com/some/url');
   ```

   where you should replace the example URL with your own.
2. If you are outputting the HTML page and sending it gradually to the user, you can just **put JavaScript redirection script** at the end of the page (so after everything has been sent):

   ```
   <script>
   window.location = 'http://example.com/some/url';
   </script>
   ```

Does any of these solutions work for you?

Answer (score 4):

```
header('Location: /page.html');
```

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you don't output anything else, then simply

```
header('Location: http://www.example.com/');
```